# Move and rename files if already exists bash

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to find and move all c,cc,ccp,cxx files from testfiles folder to /usr/local/src.I'm using:

```
find ~/testfiles -iregex '.*\.\(c\|cc\|ccp\|cxx\)$' -exec mv -i '{}' /usr/local/src \;
```

The folder contains subfolders and some files have the same name. The option that the user have is to overwrite or not the file with the -i..I am trying to give him the option if he wants to rename the file and then move it to the folder.

Comment: What is the question? Do you not get the desired behaviour? Can you create a minimal example of a failing setup?

Comment: I am trying to give the option to user just to rename the file and not to overwrite it so i can have both files

Answer (score 0):

You can spawn a `bash` command (more like a script) in the `-exec` option, like below:

```
find ~/testfiles -iregex '.*\.\(c\|cc\|ccp\|cxx\)$' -exec bash -c 'i="$(basename "$1")"; if [ -f "/usr/local/src/$i" ]; then
  read -rp"
The file \"$i\" already exists in the target directory! What do you want to do?

1) Overwrite file in target directory
2) Rename source file

: " choice;
  if [ "$choice" -eq 1 ]; then
    mv -f "$1" /usr/local/src/;
  elif [ "$choice" -eq 2 ]; then
    read -rp"New file name: " newfile;
    mv -f "$1" "/usr/local/src/$newfile";
  else
    echo "Invalid option! Skipping...";
  fi
else
  mv "$1" /usr/local/src/;
fi

' _ {} \;
```

EDIT 1: Updated code according to [SC2156](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2156).

EDIT 2: Truncated preceding absolute path for the files matched.

Comment: It runs but it does not do anything now

Comment: still..doesnt do anything

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the code itself. Which `bash` version are you running in your OS? You can find that by issuing `bash --version`.

Comment: I am running 5.0.17(1)

Comment: Think I fixed the issue now, please test it once more if you care @DragathorGRE.

Comment: Now it does move only .cxx